# Node.js add images to response

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js site with image server that is at the same machine. When I come to the gallery page, I want to display some images from my './uploads/images' folder. How can I do this?
So far, I found a function

```
fs.readdir('./uploads/images', function (err, files) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./uploads/images/'+files[0]));
});
```

but how to render a view with all these files joined?

Comment: What does this do that you don't like? Also, did you write this? Where did you get this from?

Comment: If you are hosting a website then you would just include <img> tags within an html file.  The source of the <img> tags would be the absolute path to the image you want to show.  You could then serve the html page using express.

Comment: @user2263572 this folder - uploads - should be in a folder public? because I include <img src='./uploads/images/...'> and receive error localhost/uploads/images/... not found. Now my uploads folder lies near folder public

Answer (score 0):

OK, I changed my directory path to ./public/... and it works, thanks